# PowerShell tab separated file contents import

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to import a tab separated file without any headers. I am looking for the best way to achieve this as I am currently only familiar with comma-separated imports with headers. The file to import will be named datafile.out

I have tried the below, but I am unable to access a single value from a row by using `$contents[3]`; this will get the forth row. I want to get the value after each tab separation:

```
    $contents = Add-Content $file -delimted "'t"
```

Comment: That's not likely to work, given that **-delimted** is not a valid parameter of **Add-Content** (nor are **-Delimited** or **-Delimiter**). A good habit, especially if you're new to PowerShell, is to tab-complete parameter names. That way you'll know when you're trying to use one that doesn't exist (type `Add-Content -Del`<tab> and you'll get nothing).

Comment: Just the idea of importing data using Add-Content indicates a misunderstanding of some very fundamental aspects of Powershell and failure to do even basic research (get-help) on the cmdlet before asking for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are asking, but if you are trying to import a tab-separated file that doesn't have a header line, then you could do it like this:

```
$contents = Import-Csv SomeFile.txt -Delimiter "`t" -Header ColumnName1,ColumnName2,ColumnName3
```

Change the column names in the `-Header` switch as necessary.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. For the -Header tag how can I get the tab seperated column number as I dont have any headers listed? So say I am wanting to get the firstname 'John' as shown on the right. There are no headers.

 Row1start: Jsmith 1253637 John Smith

Comment: @user3175140, You just make up the column names. If your line was like this **1253637<tab>John<tab>Smith**, for example, then you could specify the header like this: **-Header ID,FirstName,LastName**. You don't have to use those names. You could use **GivenName**, for example, instead of **FirstName**. Just use something reasonable.

Comment: The tab separated file is auto extracted from a system at given times throughout the day. The file that is extracted does not contain headers, is there a way to reference a columns/tab separated id number rather than a columns header.

Comment: @user3175140, if there is no header, then you can specify the header yourself with the **-Header** switch. This the third time I've said that. Do you understand this point?

Comment: It wasnt clear that the -Header tag can be used simply for referencing . ie -Header ColumnName1,ColumnName2,ColumnName3. Where ColumnName1 is simply the value in a specifc row in the first column. However you have answered my question +1